# Unable to add the parameter field in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I am developing a windows application and am using crystal reports in it.

I am trying to add the parameter field in it, however, when I click on the OK button, it is just not working.

Am I missing anything out?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have Uninstalled and Installed Crystal Reports, its working fine now...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Paebbels How does that not answer the question? It clearly described what fixed the problem (which might have been a bug of crystal reports)...

Comment: Your answer popped up on my review list as a *low quality/short answer*. I voted that this answer is more of a comment than an answer. The system then posts automated comments in my name :(.

Answer (score 0):

There could be 2 possiblities.

1) Just checked on my PC, just be Right Clicking Parameters -> Add -> Leaving everything as is (defaults) I am able to create a parameter. You must have changed some setting inside. Use defaults to confirm that you are able to create one.

2) You are missing the *Value Field*. This field specifies CR which database field to work upon when the parameter is used.
The drop-down will list all the database fields available for use.

Besides, here are few tutorials that explain how to use parameters that might guide you.

[Good tutorial on parameters in CR](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=682112&seqNum=3)

[Video Tutorial for the same](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NkmXGu2fqF8)

Comment: Tried everything, simply not working... should Uninstall and Install crystal reports ?